# How to fix a few bad lines in conjugate-pair split-radix FFT in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I found some very helpful C-code for the twiddle factors used in a high-performance conjugate-pairs split-radix FFT.  I need this to run in Python so the FFT can be easily integrated into my Rhino 6 Python app for precision agriculture.  This is the C-code:

```
static size_t const kMaxN = 2048;
static complexf s_twiddles[(kMaxN / 4) * 2];
static void twiddle_init()
{
    for (size_t N = 1; N <= kMaxN / 4; N *= 2)
    {
        double const kPi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
        double step = -2.0 * kPi / (double)(N * 4);
        complexf *twiddle = s_twiddles + N;

        for (size_t k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            double phase = step * (double)k;
            twiddle[k] = complexf((float)cos(phase), (float)sin(phase));
        }
    }
}
```

The Python code looks like this:

```
twiddle = [(0.0+1j*0.0) for i in xrange(2048)]
def make_twiddle():
    global twiddle
    for N in [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048]:
        step = -2.0*pi/(N*4)
        #*twiddle = s_twiddles + N # Do not know what to do with this line.
        for k in xrange(N)
            phase = step*k
            twiddle[k] = cos(phase) + 1j*sin(phase)
```

There is one line that I do not understand how to translate:

```
    *twiddle = s_twiddles + N
```

Is this line saying something about the size of the twiddle array in C?  Is it saying that the twiddle array needs to be the size of the s_twiddles array plus N more?  Or does it have something to due with the address? A similar line appears in the middle of the main FFT code:

```
        complexf const *twiddle = s_twiddles + N/4;
        complexf const &w = twiddle[k];
        // Twiddle
        Zk *= w;
        Zdk *= std::conj(w);
```

I translated this to Python using:

```
        w = twiddle[k]
        Zk *= w;
        Zdk *= complex(w).conjugate()
```

but the FFT is not working correctly in Python, with both the frequency peaks in the wrong place and at the wrong amplitude.  Obviously I cannot leave out the effect of the line:

```
        complexf const *twiddle = s_twiddles + N/4;
```

but I am at a loss at how to replace it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP wants to close question.

Comment: If you want to remove the question you can do so using the hyper link under your question.

Answer (score 0):

`complexf *twiddle` is a pointer. In C/C++ the 'name' of an array is a pointer to the first element of it, and the addresses are in order. So `*twiddle = s_twiddles + N` means that `twiddle` will point to the N-th element of `s_twiddles`.
The python equivalent to that should be `twiddle = s_twiddles[N:]`. You seem to have gotten rid of `s_twiddle` in your translation, but I am not sure why..

Comment: I have moved on to using a conjugate-pair split-radix FFT which does the twiddle factors another way and eliminates the problem above.  Thanks for helping with this version.